# How to receive new PHPSESSID in Cordova (with android)?

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an app with Cordova (with android) which contains IFrame.

The IFrame calls remote website which use PHPSESSID for authentication.

I expected the IFrame will get a new PHPSESSID when the app restart like as stock browser.

But, Even i set cookie expire time in the remote server like below.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

Cordova always loads the same PHPSESSID.

I have done this testing on stock browser and desktop browser. 
Both case showed me what i expected.

Although i need to do backup and recovery PHPSESSID for preparing low memory situation, i want to get a new PHPSESSID when the app was created or recreated.
Because of reason of security.

Does anyone have any idea of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: (my preferred)

- create a server method to call for destroy you session

  ```
   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
     $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
     foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
         $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
         $name = trim($parts[0]);
         setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
         setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
     }
  }
  ```

Solution 2:

- clean cookies from client side in javascript, then reload the home.

  ```
  function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      var cookie = cookies[i];
      var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
      var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
      document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you, Danilo Calzetta. Good ideas!.

Comment: I can not try your ideas directly now. I will tell you the resulting as soon as i can. Thank you again.